# How to call late bound extension method from VB.NET (Framework)

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods, late-binding

I have successfully used MQTTnet in C#. One customer insists that I use VB.NET, so I converted my C# to VB.NET. Now I get an error, 'Error  BC36908 Late-bound extension methods are not supported' on the line `Await managedMqttClientPublisher.EnqueueAsync(message)`.

```
  Private managedMqttClientPublisher As IManagedMqttClient 
  Private IsConnected As Boolean = False

  Private IsStartProcessing As Boolean = False
  Public Async Function PublisherStart() As Task
    Try
      If Not IsStartProcessing Then
        IsStartProcessing = True
        If Not IsConnected Then
          Dim mqttFactory = New MqttFactory()

          Dim tlsOptions = New MqttClientTlsOptions With {
.UseTls = False,
.IgnoreCertificateChainErrors = True,
.IgnoreCertificateRevocationErrors = True,
.AllowUntrustedCertificates = True
}

          Dim options = New MqttClientOptions With {
.ClientId = "ClientPublisher",
.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.V311,
              .ChannelOptions = New MqttClientTcpOptions With {
  .Server = "localhost",
  .Port = MQTTMessagePort,
  .TlsOptions = tlsOptions
}
}

          If options.ChannelOptions Is Nothing Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException()
          End If

          options.Credentials = New MqttClientCredentials("username", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password"))

          options.CleanSession = True
          options.KeepAlivePeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
          managedMqttClientPublisher = mqttFactory.CreateManagedMqttClient()
          'Me.managedMqttClientPublisher.ConnectedAsync += AddressOf OnPublisherConnected
          AddHandler Me.managedMqttClientPublisher.ConnectedAsync, AddressOf OnPublisherConnected
          AddHandler Me.managedMqttClientPublisher.DisconnectedAsync, AddressOf OnPublisherDisconnected
          AddHandler Me.managedMqttClientPublisher.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync, AddressOf Me.Subscriber.HandleReceivedApplicationMessage

          Await managedMqttClientPublisher.StartAsync(New ManagedMqttClientOptions With {
.ClientOptions = options
})
        End If
        IsConnected = True
      End If
    Catch ex As Exception
      AccutrolLibrary.Logging.LogException(ex)
    End Try
    IsStartProcessing = False
  End Function

  Public Async Function Publish(ByVal Topic As String, ByVal PayloadString As String) As Task(Of String)
    Dim Result = ""
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    Try
      'sb.Append("{\"Topic\": \"");
      'sb.Append(Topic + "\",");
      'sb.Append("\"Message\": \"");
      'sb.Append(Message + "\",}");
      'var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
      Dim payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PayloadString)
      Dim message = New MqttApplicationMessageBuilder().WithTopic(Topic.Trim()).WithPayload(payload).WithQualityOfServiceLevel(MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce).WithRetainFlag().Build()

      If managedMqttClientPublisher IsNot Nothing Then
        Await managedMqttClientPublisher.EnqueueAsync(message)
      End If
    Catch ex As Exception
      'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Occurs", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      Result = "Error: " & ex.Message
    End Try
    Return Result
  End Function
```

I have searched the Internet to discover how to correct this error. The only entries I have found so far discuss modifying the library that contains the late-bound extension method. I am not comfortable modifying the MQTTnet library.

I have tried replacing the call with `Await IManagedMqttClient.EnqueueAsync(message)`, but that did not correct the error.

Is there a way to structure the call to the late-bound extension method so that it does not produce an error?

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Just call the [static method](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/aabf180b23c20879175d4102062ce84eb0563d7a/Source/MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient/ManagedMqttClientExtensions.cs#L15) directly: Await ManagedMqttClientExtensions.EnqueueAsync(managedMqttClientPublisher, message)

Comment: HansPassant: This did not produce an error. I will try to run it to see if it behaves. @Amessihel Are you asking for more code, or for less code?

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your code but the request could be for both more and less code. A minimal, reproducible example is literally ALL the code that is required to demonstrate the issue and NOTHING that is not required. We should be able to copy and paste your code and run it to see the issue but they're should be nothing that could be removed and the issue still be demonstrated. You should be able to tell what the entrails from your own testing and debugging.

Comment: @HamiltonWoods a minimal code. :)